# ValueError: time data 'In 00 days 23:07:56' does not match format 'In %d days %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I am trying to parse my date string with time library. But i have an error in parsing.

```py
# Example is 'In 0 days 23:07:56'
client['license_time_start'] = time.strptime('In 0 days 23:07:56', 'In %d days %H:%M:%S')
```

ValueError: time data 'In 00 days 23:07:56' does not match format 'In %d days %H:%M:%S'

Comment: could you add the value of `client['license_time']` to your question

Comment: Yes i added. Thank you

Comment: Error does not match code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because date can't be `0`. It has to be an positive integer.

Therefore, this produces an error:-

```
time.strptime('In 0 days 23:07:56', 'In %d days %H:%M:%S')
# ValueError: time data 'In 0 days 23:07:56' does not match format 'In %d days %H:%M:%S'
```

This doesn't:-

```
time.strptime('In 01 days 23:07:56', 'In %d days %H:%M:%S')
# time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=23, tm_min=7, tm_sec=56, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```