# ValueError: time data '0 days 00:07:02.710529' does not match format '%d %H:%M:%S' python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm having trouble converting string variables into timedelta variable. 
According to this question: [ValueError: time data 'In 00 days 23:07:56' does not match format 'In %d days %H:%M:%S'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56993382/valueerror-time-data-in-00-days-230756-does-not-match-format-in-d-days-h)

you can solve it by changing 00 days into 01 days because `date` can't be 0, but in my case, that variable is the output of time difference calculations. Is there another solution without changing my variable.

This is the code:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
print(df.iloc[4,1])
print(type(df.iloc[4,1]))
t = datetime.datetime.strptime((df.iloc[4,1]),"%d days %H:%M:%S")
```

output before the error:

```
0 days 00:07:02.710529
<class 'str'>
```

**error**:

```
 File "C:\Users\khou\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py", line 359, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))

ValueError: time data '0 days 00:07:02.710529' does not match format '%d days %H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: first you should check what value you get if you use `"%d days %H:%M:%S"` to getnerate time - `import time` `time.strftime("%d days %H:%M:%S")` . It gives me `'25 days 16:13:14'` and there is no milliseconds. You may need `%S.%s` OR you may have to remove milliseconds.

Comment: [How can I parse a time string containing milliseconds in it with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698223/how-can-i-parse-a-time-string-containing-milliseconds-in-it-with-python)

Comment: it seems like it would help me out, but when I tried to test it, it raised an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'` when I googled it it advised me to put a null check to avoid it `try: if !(match is None):`
        `d = match.groupdict()` but I don't know where to place it exactly